# How to add JS files in Jhipster and integrate a new template

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jhipster, angular-template

I'm working on spring boot / Angular 6 project with the jhipster framework,

I want to customize and integrate an other template, I added the css and the image

folders in Content folder in the project and I imported all the css files in

vendor.css, but i don't know how to include the js files. Any help please or any

recommendation to integrate a template. Thank u.

Comment: Is your template an npm module? Which template ? Have you followed the example in your project's README.md on how to manage deps? Can you add js files to vendor.ts?

Comment: I added the js files in a folder in content,  i imported them in vendor.ts and i enabled the script in the index.html. It's a bootstrap template